# JSOUP do not connect with specific webpage

Tags: java, parsing, proxy, jsoup

I would like to connect to [https://www.sierra.com/] while I am connected to the VPN. When I am trying to connect I get error
`java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`, but if try to parse google.com all works fine. Why does it happen?

```
Document page = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36").timeout(0).get();
```

Comment: Is the closing bracket ] in the url should be there?

Comment: No, there should be clear URL

Comment: It works fine for me (without the bracket of course).

Comment: Hello, what VPN service do you use?

Comment: I will appreciate if you give advice what VPN do you use?

Comment: I don't use VPN.